# Download form URL and upload to Google Drive in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file from URL after downloading it, but it does not work as expected. I have tried searching on Google and found some way to do that, like DriveApp (I can't find how to import DriveApp class, I'm new in javascript).

So, is there any other way to do that? I've successfully uploaded the file to Google Drive, but Google Drive can't read the content. I think I did something wrong after downloading the file, could you guys help me correct it, please.

Thank you in advance!

Download from URL:

```
var _this_ = this;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', this.link, true);
xhr.responseType='blob';  
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (xhr.status == 200)
  {
    _this_.uploadToGoogleDrive(xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

And upload to Google Drive:

```
uploadFile(title,data) {
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

    let fileData = new Blob([data], {
        'type': this.media.getMimeType(title)
    });

    //const contentType = 'application/json';
    const contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';

    var metadata = {
        'name': title,
        'mimeType': contentType
    };

    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n' +
        fileData +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody
    });
    request.execute();
}
```